# Objective C textfield formatter commas every two number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like inserting commas to every two number in uitextfield while typing but my code isn't work and I don't know where is the mistake I've made.

Idea: when user type `23456789` then format it to `23,45,67,89` while they're typing.

Here is my code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
if([string length]==0)
{
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"-"];
    [formatter setGroupingSize:4];
    [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    [formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:2];
    NSString *num = textField.text ;
    num= [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]]];
    textField.text=str;
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    return YES;
}
else {
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
    [formatter setGroupingSize:2];
    [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    [formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:2];
    NSString *num = textField.text ;
    if(![num isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        num= [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
        NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]]];
        textField.text=str;
    }

    //NSLog(@"%@",str);
    return YES;
}
```

When I type, number always show 3 char before insert commas like this `1,23,44,567`

Any idea?

Comment: Where is this method? What is `string`? Update your question by showing the entire method that contains this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it appears as if there's a bug in setGroupingSize, and to work around it you should change

```
[formatter setGroupingSize:2]
```

to

```
[formatter setGroupingSize:1]
```

Which solves the immediate problem.  But there's some other issues in your code.  Do you want to use NumberWithDouble and doubleValue, or should you be using integers?  How are negative number handled?  What is the range of valid inputs?   What happens if the user tries to edit the middle of the text?  Why is there a different formatter when string length is 0?  Is this really the best way to collect input from the user